# Install windows service from installaware

Tags: c#, windows, service, installation, installaware

I have created a windows service using C#

I can install it manually using UnstallUtil.exe

I want to create an installer with installAware. 
Could you assist me in how do I have to do to set the installer to automatically install the service?
(I have seen that there is a service tab in Advanced options but I cannot manage to make it work)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install the service using InstallAware,

1. Switch to Design mode and go to Advanced Options -> Services.
2. Button "New..." -> Install Service
3. In the dialog that opens, you will have to set up the "Service File" tab and the "Service Properties" tab correctly.
4. In the "Service File" tab, you have to select the service file and the target folder. Enter the full path of the service file (.exe), or select it using the Browse button. The Target Folder will normally be entered as $TARGETDIR$\.
5. In the "Service Properties" tab, you have to enter the service name. You may also enter additional information in this tab, but that is optional.

This post assumes that you have included the files for the service in the installer (Setup Architecture -> Files).

Hope this helps.